# VSTO: General Install Error Windows 10

Tags: ms-word, vsto, windows-10, clickonce

We have a VSTO Application that is installed on many machines. If the Add-In is already installed, there is no issue. If you try to uninstall or install, you get the following error message:

> The following Microsoft Office solution cannot be installed due to a general installer error: App_Name.vsto
>
> 0x80070002

This application has been working without hiccups for almost a year now. Our Sys Admin and I believe we've narrowed it down to a mandatory Windows 10 [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3173428) as our base Windows 10 image has it working fine and it works on Windows 7 no issue. However, the update is already pushed out and nothing is showing up in the logs.

I know the `VSTOInstaller.exe.Config` file has been the cause for several of these installer issues, however I cannot find that file on any of our machines even though I **KNOW** I modified one machine and changed the name to `VSTOInstaller.exe.Config.Old` for the `Business.fba` error some have gotten. I assume an update somehow packaged the config file into the `.exe`.

The Windows 7 machines also don't have the `Config` file as well...

What we've tried:

1. Searching for an older `.Config` file to place in the folder
2. Rolling back to a previous version
3. Recompiling
4. Changing the publish destination folder and setting version back to version 1.0.0.0
5. **Update:** Placing a `VSTOInstaller.Exe.Config` then a `VSTOInstaller.Config` in the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0` folder
6. **Update:** Running repair then doing an uninstall/reinstall on `Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime (x64)` program from Control Panel.
7. **Update:** Cleared Application Event Log
8. **Update:** Stopped Windows Update service, Renamed `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` folder to `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistributionOld`, then restarted the Windows Update service.

I'm at a loss. Any help is **GREATLY** appreciated.

If anyone has the `VSTOInstaller.exe.Config` file, I'd love to try and place that in the folder to see if it works.

**Version:**

- Word Version - 16.0.6769.2040
- VS Version - 14.0.25420.1
- OS Version - 1511 (OS Build 10586.494)

Comment: Do you mean C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.config? I don't see a file named VSTOInstaller.exe.config. Mine has references to "Microsoft.Office.BusinessApplications.Runtime.DeploymentAction.HttpFbaRequestCreator".

Comment: I don't even have a `VSTOInstaller.config` file in there. It is not in Windows 7 folders either. But I know it was titled `VSTOInstaller.exe.co‌​nfig`.

Comment: Which is why if someone has a `.Config` where I can look at the xml and put a copy of the file into the corresponding folder and see if the VSTOs launch after that. That was going to be my next troubleshooting step but I can't find a single `.Config` on any machine.

Comment: Well, here's the file I do have. Maybe it will help. http://pastebin.com/S4FQiUUK

Comment: Fiddlesticks... thanks for your help, @Chris, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: This is probably a shot in the dark @GibralterTop, but I've seen a number of different VSTO installer issues -- ones where the add-in worked if already there, but the installer failed otherwise -- when the [Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217) were not installed properly. These tools are required to run VSTO add-ins created with Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015 and the Windows 10 update might have fried them. You might want to try downloading them from the link in this comment and reinstalling them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @joeschwa. I should've been more specific but number 6 in the question was actually doing what you are describing. I attempted again from the link but unfortunately same result. Thanks again!

Comment: @GibralterTop, have you removed the possibility of a conflict being between ClickOnce and Windows 10 by installing directly using the command line (something like `VSTOInstaller.exe /i 'file:///C:/folderpath/App_Name.vsto'`)? More information can be found at [Customizing Office Solution Installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772078(v=vs.100).aspx). If this doesn't work, could you provide more information about the specifics of the install: Word version, VS version, Windows 10 Build, etc?

Comment: Same error. Updated question with requested information.

Comment: @GibralterTop, I found two fringe cases that may apply to you. In the first a VSTO add-in got the same error as you and [fixed the install by correcting an issue caused by Windows Update](http://www.ca.com/us/support/ca-support-online/product-content/knowledgebase-articles/tec1599149.aspx). In the second the VSTO install is bad, but a different general installer error is generated. This was solved by [clearing the applications event log](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/07c29bd3-94e9-4244-9bdf-2025bafd7621/vsto-install-error-0x80131604?forum=vsto).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get to your comment before the weekend, @joeschwa. Neither worked for me. I cleared the application event log and renamed the `Software Distribution` folder after stopping the Windows Update service and then started it after renaming.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help @GibralterTop. I hope you find the solution and post it here. Would love to know what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the error was part of a Microsoft Office update. Unsure if somehow the update listed in the question updated Office 2016 in the background somewhere.

The steps to resolution were as follows:

1. Uninstall O365 from the Control Panel
2. Download the a full removal tool and run it from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8
3. At this point after those have ran, uninstall the add-in if it was installed.
4. Reinstall O365
5. Reinstall/Install the VSTO Add-In

Easier resolution than I thought and really appreciate all the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Update error 0x80070002 or 0x80070003

Step  1: Windows Service Checklist:

Open Windows services.msc, check the following services status (If it is different set it to the recommended settings)
[enter image description here][1]
Disable any third party antivirus applications, as it may block the Windows 10 upgrade process.

Step 2: Reset Windows updates:

Resetting windows updates,  in this step we will clean up old failed updates that have been saved in the computer, let start by first disabling the windows update service.

Service Status(Start/Stop/Blank)    Automatic/manual/Disabled
Background Intelligent file Transfer    Started Automatic
Crytographic Service    Started Automatic
DCOM    service      Started    Automatic
RPC Started Automatic
Windows Modules Installer   Started Automatic
Windows Update  Started Automatic
Windows defender    Blank   Disabled
Windows firewall    Blank   Disabled

Disable Windows update service and stop the service
Now open Run command and type %windir%
Check for Software distribution folder delete the folder. (If it fails restart the computer, then try deleting it)
In Run command window type “cleanmgr” to launch disc cleanup to clean old junk files.

Restart the windows update service set it Automatic. Once completed, the windows upgrade error code 80070002 should be resolved. Try the upgrade now.  Still unlucky, get in touch with us or proceed to next step

Step  3: Dism/Readiness Tool

This step is to fix core Operating system files that are corrupted and is affecting the Windows 10 upgrade and causing the error.  Most of the cases running the tool or the command will fix the corrupted files, there are cases where some stubborn files remain. We can assist you in repairing them manually, post the log to us so we can check and revert back to you.

Depending on the OS, you have to choose proper tools,
For Windows 8 and higher use the following command in elevated command prompt.
   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

For windows 7: Download and run windows update readiness tool

microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=20858  –X64

microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=3132 – X86

Check the logs for the above tools in the following location
%windir%/logs/cbs

Post the log for further steps.

Please refer to this link for more info :

http://www.msofficelivesupport.com/windows-update/windows-10-update-error-0x80070002-or-0x80070003/